# Rails logging not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

So I've taken up the mantle on an old project at my company. It is a Rails 3.0.2 project that deploys with Capistrano. I just deployed, and one of the pages I added is crashing. I get absolutely no logging and don't know why it's happening. I've tried the following things in my `config/environments/production.rb`:

- I've tried putting nothing. I thought the defaults would work (info level debugging in `log/production.log`), but they don't.
- `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new("log/production.log")`
- `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new(STDOUT)`
- `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`

And like two more things I unfortunately can't remember any more. Any idea why I would still get nothing? No standard output in the terminal, and production.log is empty.

Comment: I'd have a look to see if there's anything that's over-riding the logging, like anything unusual in your `Gemfile`. Did you restart the server process each time after making changes?

Comment: I've been redeploying after every change. And `Gemfile` doesn't have anything strange I don't recognize except for the gem "annotate" which is grouped into development and test. Maybe that's it? I'm about to look into what annotate does.

Comment: You'll want to update to a newer version of the 3.0.x Rails to get caught up on security fixes, which may or may not fix the problem. It's worth checking if `log/development.log` works as expected in development mode.

Comment: Is it just your crash error that's not logging anything? Ie. if you try `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error "Some string here"` you still don't see anything in your logs?

Comment: @tadman - Nothing gets logged for the development log because it is set to log to STDOUT, which does work.

Comment: @smathy - I just tried doing what you said and got nothing in the logs.

Comment: I found it, I feel silly but I really didn't know about this before. I was making assumptions based off of how the other Rails project I worked on was like. I had to go to the most recent directory in releases. The log is working there.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set `log` as one of those `linked_dirs` in `config/deploy.rb` so it persists between deployments. I thought that was a default.